# Uniform Cost Search in Fully Connected Weighed Graph with a Specified Number Of Customers to Visit

Tags: python, algorithm, search, artificial-intelligence, graph-theory

The problem: you are a salesman. You have customers in an area. Also, you have office S as a starting point and office F as the target point. Before you arrive at the target point you need to visit a specified number of customers. You need to find an optimal solution with the least distance you walk. To do that you will use uniform cost search.

Input Grid is that:

[image: Input Grid]

In this grid, you gave each node a coordinate starting from left top point as (0,0). Then you create a fully connected graph because you can go to any node from any node. As you create the graph, you also calculate their manhattan distance and add it to the edges.

I used this approach when implementing my UCS algorithm : [Uniform COst Search](https://python.plainenglish.io/uniform-cost-search-ucs-algorithm-in-python-ec3ee03fca9f)

Here is my implementation

```
def ucs(graph, node):
    global number_of_steps
    global nodes
    global count
    global opened
    global closed

    resPaths = []

    while True:
        if len(opened) == 0:
            return resPaths #C6 PARENTS STAY ONE

        if getFromOpened('F') is not None:
            newpaths = paths(getFromOpened('F'))
            resPaths += newpaths

        selected_node = min(opened)

        selected_node.visitedNumber += 1

        opened.remove(selected_node)
        if not InClosed(selected_node):
            closed.append(selected_node)
        else:
            old_node = getFromClosed(selected_node.type)
            closed.remove(old_node)
            closed.append(selected_node)



        new_nodes = extendNode(selected_node) #parent meselesi çözülmeli


        if len(new_nodes) > 0:
            for new_node in new_nodes:
                oldValue = new_node.value
                new_node.value = calculateDistance(selected_node, new_node)
                if(new_node.type == 'F' and InOpened(new_node)):
                   old_node = getFromOpened(new_node.type)
                   opened.remove(old_node)
                   new_node.addParent(old_node.parent)
                   opened.append(new_node)
                elif not InClosed(new_node) and  not InOpened(new_node): ## if not in the lists
                    opened.append(new_node)
                    continue
                elif InOpened(new_node):  # if reexplored
                    old_node = getFromOpened(new_node.type)
                    if new_node.value < old_node.value:
                        opened.remove(old_node)
                        new_node.addParent(old_node.parent)
                        new_node.visitedNumber = old_node.visitedNumber
                        opened.append(new_node)
                    else:
                        old_node.addParent(new_node.parent) #it solved it almost
                elif InClosed(new_node): #THIS IS WHERE THINGS GET MESSY
                    old_node = getFromClosed(new_node.type)
                    if old_node.visitedNumber < 4:#minCustomerNo:
                        new_node.addParent(old_node.parent)
                        new_node.visitedNumber = old_node.visitedNumber
                        opened.append(new_node)
                        closed.remove(old_node)
```

The problem here is that for the input :

```
{'min': 7,'env': [
'....C1...', 
'.F......', 
'.....C2..', 
'.......C3', 
'........', 
'C4.......', 
'.C5......', 
'C6...S.C7.']}
```

The true answer is that:

```
[[7, 4], [6, 1], [5, 0], [7, 0], [7, 6], [3, 7], [2, 5], [0, 4], [1, 1]]
S,C4,C3,C5,C6,C2,C1,C0,F
```

What I found is that:

```
[7, 4],[7, 6], [6, 1], [5, 0], [7, 0], [3, 7], [2, 5], [0, 4],[1, 1]
S,C6,C4,C3,C5,C2,C1,C0,F
```

As you can see this is the answer I found before I added the InClosed(new_node) check at the end of my implementation.

**Here is the real problem**

After we start from the S, the closest is C6. In the second pass, it is chosen and it is thrown to the closed array which is like the visited arrays. But since the graph is fully connected, in the third pass when C4 is selected, I also need to visit C6 again. But it is in the closed list. So the real answer is never created because in the true answer C6 is in the 5th order even though it is visited first.

**First** I tried putting it back from closed to opened again but it creates an infinite loop.
**Second** I tried adding an attribute 'visitedNumber' to the node class. So I can limit the number of times it is put back to opened array. The limit should be the minimum number of customers to visit because it is the depth we need. When I tried it with minCustomerNo = 2, everything fine and gives the correct solution. But as the number grows it started to be a program never ends.

So what should I do exactly to both visit nodes again but also create a visited system?

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is just as good as the "true answer" -- same cost and same customers visited, so no problem there.

Your program is not correct, though, because the optimal solution won't always reach every customer by the shortest path to that customer.

You should be doing UCS on a much larger [implicit graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_graph), where each node captures not just where you are, but also which customers you've already visited.

Comment: It is the same customers but not the same cost actually. The cost of the true answer is 29 whereas my answer is 33. The cost is the sum of manhattan distances between the coordinates.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Now I was able to achieve the right implementation with an implicit graph.